# Unique rule, ignore null value

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a `FormRequest` where i want to validate the uniqueness of the field `fiscal_id` when updating the row, the validation kind of work, but the problem is that `fiscal_id` may be null, so if when updating it i send null, the unique rule do not pass.

```php
'fiscal_id' => [
    'sometimes', 
    Rule::unique('table', 'fiscal_id')->where(function($query) {
        $query->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id);
    })->ignore($this->route('customer')->id)
]
```

How can i validate the uniqueness of the `fiscal_id` when its `null` (Because there are other field with `null` so it fails).

Comment: Try [nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) validation?

Comment: Yes you should use nullable instead of sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

try to separate validation for create and update like this

```
public function rules() {
    // rules for updating record
    if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
        return [
            'fiscal_id' => [
                 'nullable',
                 Rule::unique('table', 'fiscal_id')->where(function($query) {
                    $query->whereNull('deleted_at')
                 ->where('company_id',auth()->user()->company_id);
                 })->ignore($this->route('customer')->id)
             ]
        ];
    } else {
    // rules for creating record
        return [
            'fiscal_id' => [
                 'required',
                 Rule::unique('table', 'fiscal_id')->where(function($query) {
                    $query->whereNull('deleted_at')
                 ->where('company_id',auth()->user()->company_id);
                 })
             ]
        ];
    }

}
```